# each() and multiple events trigger the same function

Tags: jquery

I want run some code on each `select` on page load and re-run it by some events on each `select` separately. currently done with following:

```
jquery(function(){
  $('#myID select').each(function(){
    alert('SE');
  });

  $('#myID select').bind('keyup keypress blur change',function(){
    alert('SE');
  });
});
```

Can I merge them into one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may trigger one of the events on DOM ready:

```
$(function() {
    $("#myID select").bind("keyup keypress blur change", function() {
        alert("SE");
    }).keyup();  // or .trigger("keyup");
});
```